# batch: continue previous table?

Tags: batch-file, call, label

ive been googling but couldn't find any answere so I decided to post another post up here. 
what i want to achieve is that lets say: your script works is currently working with label 5,  but in this label you would like to call up another label. lets say label 1. and the settings for label 1 is to goto label2. but as you called label 1 through label 5. then label 1 will ignore this and when you press enter. you will come back to label 5 instead. and continue where "you left of" and perceed to label6. as an example. is this an possiblie function? if so. how to achieve this?

:label1
goto label 2

:label 2
goto label3.
:label3
goto label4
:label4
goto label5

:label5
call label 1
(return to label5)
goto label 6

:label6

Answer (score 0):

you want `call` instead of `goto`. It returns with `goto :eof`. You probably have to change your logic to implement that.

```
@echo off
echo now we jump through the code...
call :label1
echo here again
call :label2
echo again here. Let's call label1 again.
call :label1
echo finished.
goto :eof

:Label1
echo you called Label1
goto :eof

:Label2
echo you called Label2
goto :eof
```

Comment: You need a Label2.  ;)

Comment: ok so i did a run on your script and it works. this is the concept i need. but im afraid i do not understand how this really works. so is there anyone that can break down the logic for me and make me understand it? im afraid i cannot get to use this clever idea if i dont understand how it realy works :P

Comment: OH WAIT i think i get it !!!!.. however i got this line: IF %Q%==/cmd.help call :helpcmd & pause>nul & goto networkscan  and obviously that didnt work out right.... how would i need to change this line to make it function? (i guess the c# method didnt work out) xDD

Comment: your line calls `:help`, returns, continues with `pause` and after keypress  goes to `networkscan`. Exactly, what I would expect.